# Angular - retrieve data from related tables with ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: angular, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have many related tables with one to many relationship created with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core Web API like this:

```
public class code
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string productCode { get; set; }
    public bool direction { get; set; }
    public bool printFace { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public bool color { get; set; }
    public int typeId { get; set; }        

    public productType productType { get; set; }

    public int sizeId { get; set; }        

    public productSize productSize { get; set; }

    public int weightId { get; set; }        
    public productWeight productWeight { get; set; }

    public int materialId { get; set; }        
    public productMaterial productMaterial { get; set; }
}

public class productWeight
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int weight { get; set; }

    public List<code> codes { get; set; }
}

public class productType
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string typeName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<code> codes { get; set; }
}
```

and so on....

In Angular, I am trying to retrieve the data from code tables and its related tables

In Angular I have an interface to simulate the data which I want to get (like view model)

```
export interface IProduct {
  id: number,
  productCode: string,
  direction: boolean,
  printFace: boolean,
  number: number,
  price: number,
  color: boolean,
  sizeId: number,
  typeId: number,
  weightId: number,
  materialId: number
}
```

but I can't do it well? How can I get the data here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating separated interface to every table and in the main table(Iproduct which refer to code table)
create a property with type of it's related  table
example:
for productMaterial table:
IproductMaterial.interface.ts:

```
export interface IproductMaterial{
  id:number,
  material:string
}
```

and in the main interface:
Iproduct.interface.ts"

```
export interface IProduct{
  id:number,
  productCode:string,
  direction:boolean,
  printFace:boolean,
  number:number,
  price:number,
  color:boolean,
  sizeId:number,
  typeId:number,
  weightId:number,
  materialId:number,
  **productMaterial:IproductMaterial**
}
```

and by this way I could display the data easily